# Overriding data when UITableview cell scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created cells in UITableView. Cells are generating dynamically from array, it fits  into cells properly too.
But when I scroll down and again scroll up my old values of same array get replaced with last values of same array.
I want all values of array in sequence depending on scrolling up or down. Below is my code, please let me know where I am making mistake...

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    LineDetailCustomCell *cell = (LineDetailCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LineDetailCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

           return cell;
```

---

Please find images with question description

[image]

This second image come when I scroll down, its working fine for scroll down.

[image]

But when I scroll up labels get overridden with new values instead of as shown in first image. That means label 01 , 02 , 03 ... replace with next values

[image]

Comment: how many custom cells do you have..??

Comment: How are you assigning values to your cell??

Comment: @MayankJain : One custom cell, which I am using in for loop.

Comment: Once you change any value in a particular cell, the same value has to be updated in its data model.

Comment: you are creating cell, but where are u setting the cell values like title etc..

Comment: I don't see how you're getting any values in your cell to be being with. Where do you setup the cell values - title, image, etc?

Comment: I am creating labels programmatically within cellForRowAtIndexPath and assigning text to labels. Adding labels to cell as subview.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a property of type NSMutableArray named `items` and it has data in it (which are strings)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
```

Then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    LineDetailCustomCell *cell = (LineDetailCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LineDetailCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSString *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = item;
    return cell;
}
```

Make sure that the reuse identifier for LineDetailCustomCell is set as `SimpleTableCell` from the Xib. This is needed for recycling the cells.

Comment: Please find question with image description

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];

//static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

NSArray *views=[cell.contentView subviews];
for(int i=0;i<[views count];i++)
{
    UIView *tempView=[views objectAtIndex:i];
    [tempView removeFromSuperview];
    tempView = nil;
}


if (cell == nil) {

   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}
}
```